# a WITH workaround for MySQL

Tags: mysql

How to convert this `with` part to MySQL?

```
SET @start  = '20210101';
SET @end  = '20211231';
        
WITH cte AS   
(  
    SELECT dt = DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@start) - 1), @start)  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, dt)  
    FROM cte  
    WHERE dt < DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@end) - 1), @end)  
)
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,dt) Name, DAY(EOMONTH(dt)) as Days into RESULT_TABLE
FROM cte
```

P.S. as far as I know I cant use WITH in MySQL since version 8.0. But what about version prior to 8.0?

Comment: I think you will find its the other way round, version wize

Comment: what rdbms is that from?  it is different from mysql syntax in a number of ways

Comment: I changed DECLARE to SET. But I don't know what to do with 'WITH AS'

Comment: It looks like you just need to insert one row per month, with the first day of each month, into a result table. The simple workaround if you don't have support for recursive CTE syntax is to write a loop in your client programming language. Every language should have functions to do date arithmetic and produce a loop over a series of dates like you need.

Comment: I interpret this question to be asking what if we are _not_ using MySQL 8.0 and therefore cannot have the CTE feature? The answers include use of recursive CTE syntax. Am I interpreting the question incorrectly? Can you clarify which version of MySQL you use? Run `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: @BillKarwin I couldn't tell if they were asking for pre-8 or not; if they indicate pre-8, then it will be important to know what the expected maximum range of dates is

Comment: @BillKarwin yep! I need a solution for pre-8. The range of dates is the whole year (1st of January till 31 of December)

Comment: If you need a solution for MySQL 5.x, then I don't understand why you accepted an answer that uses a CTE. The CTE syntax requires MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a table from a `recursive query` this way:

```
SET @start  = '20210101';
SET @end  = '20211231';

CREATE TABLE result_table AS
        
WITH RECURSIVE cte(dt) AS   
(  
    SELECT DATE(@start)
    
    UNION ALL  
    
    SELECT DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    FROM cte  
    WHERE DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) < @end  
)

SELECT MONTHNAME(dt) AS Name, DAY(LAST_DAY(dt)) AS Days
FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql 8 or mariadb 10.2+, you would do this like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT DATE_SUB(@start, INTERVAL DAY(@start) - 1 DAY) AS dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    FROM cte
    WHERE dt < DATE_SUB(@end, INTERVAL DAY(@end) - 1 DAY)
)
SELECT MONTHNAME(dt) AS Name, DAY(LAST_DAY(dt)) AS Days
FROM cte;
```

But I'm not sure I understand what the "into RESULT_TABLE" was doing.

Comment: still says that WITh is not valid at this position :(
into RESULT_TABLE - I think it's gonna put the query result into a new table

Comment: something like create view?  or do you mean inserting into an existing table?  re not valid at this position, what does `select version();` show?  and please edit your question to show exactly what you are trying.